# Reuse drupal password hashes in htpasswd

Tags: .htaccess, drupal, hash, drupal-7, .htpasswd

I have an existing Drupal 7 database with password hashes like this:

```
U$S$92keK3LGE6O3i/yZoftycq9AXzAlwGPqn3nfn2gRO6z6U0Q.9IPM
U$S$9SStyGBYv95n.yfhyZzNdHggooRGOxem6zgbDreZO34LgxLYQN5z
...
```

I want to temporarily re-use these login accounts for a htpasswd protected static page on another server. I understand Drupal uses sha-512 but htpasswd only supports sha-1 (and crypt + md5).

Is there a way I can use these hashes with htpasswd?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's theoretically possible if you fancy recompiling htpasswd to pass the Drupal salt to the glibc2 version of crypt with an ID of 6. I wouldn't suggest it is feasible.

Comment: haha, OK. I ended up using PHP for the sha-512 authentication instead.